# Deploying Struts2 Application without ContextPath

Tags: java, tags, struts2, contextpath

I've got a struts2 application running under a contextpath "/path" on my local tomcat without problems. When I deploy it on a webserver (using a proxy to redirect from "http://www.domain.com" to "myserver:8080/path/") Struts does all kinds of strange things.

First, it includes the context in -tags. That can be turned off by an attribute. But sadly, it also includes the path in the action attributes of my forms, so a login form points to "http://www.domain.com/path/login.action" instead of "http://www.domain.com/login.action" ...

Is there a possibility so somehow change the default context that is added here or turn this off for forms? (I'd like to keep the -tags, only way round seems to be to use default HTML forms.) Thanks in advance!

Comment: I did some tests and I think you'll have to resort to using the default HTML form element and setting the action with the `<s:url>` tag.  The odd thing is that the WebWork docs (https://cwiki.apache.org/WW/form.html) show an includeContext param on the `<s:form>` tag.  This is the first time I've seen behaviour missing from Struts2 that's in WebWork.

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for your answer. Sadly, the action attribute of the <s:form> doesn't take a <s:url>. Only workaround seems to be not using the s:form tag - which I don't want to.

Comment: Using includeContext="false" also doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that others also had the problem, but the framework makers don't seem to think that this is an issue. My solutions:

- use includeContext="false" in all s:url-tags
- instead of the s:form tag, use a usual form, set the action to "actionname.action" and include a simple table with tablerows () for each field. You still can use s:textfield and such.
- sadly HTTP sessions won't work anymore as they get set for the path "/path" (the ApplicationPath). This is due to the cookie that saves the JSESSIONID being set to /path. This means that your visitors will only get session variables stored when they're at http://www.domain.com/path/login.action and that those will be lost when they get redirected back to http://www.domain.com/interestingstuff.action ... my solution is a hack that requires setting the JSESSIONID cookie clientside via JavaScript as described here: [Struts2: Session Problem (after reverse proxy)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3389235/struts2-session-problem-after-reverse-proxy)

Hope this helps someone ... if you find nicer solutions, please let me know. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Though am answering very late to this question, but I reached this page recently when I was facing the same problem.

The application that I was working upon was appending the context-root viz. 'myContextRoot' to my url on localhost and it was working perfectly there. For eg., as mentioned above the action 'myAction' was becoming
    `http://localhost:8050/myContextRoot/myAction.action`
But the moment I deployed it on a server, it stopped working, then after searching like hell, I found a solution for me. I am deploying an EAR file on glassfish and there we have a file application.xml. In application.xml I had a tag 'context-root' whose value was 'myContextRoot' which I changed to '/' and after that I got my url as on localhost and

Hope it may help :)