# merge two web modules

Tags: tomcat, struts2

I have two web applications.

Application 1 -

struts.xml

```
<result name="store" type="redirectAction">
            <param name="actionName">storeslist</param>
            <param name="namespace"></param>

            <param name="tok">${token}</param>
        </result>
```

Application 2

struts.xml

```
<action class="com.aa.store" name="storeslist"  >

        <result>/WEB-INF/jsp/store.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

Now I need to implement this

Application1 contains one link 'store' clicking on this link it has to go to store page of Application2

How to do this?

I tried  `<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn"/>` in tomcat `server.xml` but did not work.

`emptySessionPath="true"` in `<connector...>` of tomcat `server.xml` still did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge this does not work at the moment *without absolute links* because Struts2 always prepends `http://server.domain.tld/appname` to all links. If you have a solution, please post an answer as I would be very interested about this myself. My workaround can be found here: [Deploying Struts2 Application without ContextPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3344148/deploying-struts2-application-without-contextpath)